# Eigen : Using a quaternion to set the rotation matrix of a Eigen::Isometry3d

Tags: c++, matrix, eigen

can anyone help me with eigen ?
I have a quaternion values (w,x,y,z) to set a rotation matrix for an Isometry3D variable.
To do so I tried using the methods `matrix()` and `toRotationMatrix ()` but I have the error :

```
error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘const LinearMatrixType {aka const Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 3>}’ and ‘Eigen::RotationBase<Eigen::Quaternion<double>, 3>::RotationMatrixType {aka Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 3>}’)
     transform.rotation() = quaternion.matrix();error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘const LinearMatrixType {aka const Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 3>}’ and ‘Eigen::RotationBase<Eigen::Quaternion<double>, 3>::RotationMatrixType {aka Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 3>}’)
     transform.rotation() = quaternion.matrix();
```

I then tried to set it by using :
`transform.rotation(quaternion.matrix());`

And I have the following error :

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘Eigen::Transform<double, 3, 1>::rotation(Eigen::RotationBase<Eigen::Quaternion<double>, 3>::RotationMatrixType)’
     transform.rotation(quaternion.matrix());
```

The complete declaration of the variables is :

```
Eigen::Isometry3d transform;
transform.translation() << 0.0, 0.0, 0.88446;
Eigen::Quaternion<double> quaternion(0.96593, 0.0, 0.25878, 0.0);
transform.rotation(quaternion.matrix());
```

Can someone help me please ?

Comment: Try `transform.rotate(quaternion.matrix())`

Comment: Thank you for your help that solved my problem !